# If Gibbs energy of activation is positive, how is the change to the transition state possible?

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy, transition-state-theory

The Gibbs energy increases from the reactants to the transition state, but according to the Second Law of Thermodynamics, entropy of the universe can only increase. Why is the transition state possible then?

Comment: Oh no, not **that** dilemma again! Btw, welcome to chemistry.SE!

Comment: Thanks. If you know the answer, though, could please explain?

Comment: Wait...You mean there can't be an entropy decrease?

Comment: That's what I thought - doesn't the second law say that?

Comment: The thermodynamics laws that your studied are valid only for some conditions. It is needed that the system be macroscopyic. Also this law only gives probabilities. It is posible to extend the theory to other areas. Doing so, in molecular cases, it is not too much unprobable this change for one molecule. All the molecules changing (that is what your can calculate with your thermodynamics) is highly unprobable.

Comment: Is it because, though the Gibbs energy of the individual molecules as they react increases to the transition state, for the system as a whole, till equilibrium the Gibbs energy is decreasing, and we can only look at the Gibbs energy change of a macroscopic system since Thermodynamics only deals with macroscopic systems?

Comment: Also Gibbs energy or entropy are only defined for macroscopic systems - a few molecules can't be given values of entropy or Gibbs energy. The Gibbs energy of activation for that set of molecules must be, I think, extrapolating by finding it for an entire macroscopic system converting to the transition state, and then diving it by the number of molecules in that system.

Comment: Actually you can get something like Gibbs energy per molecule (its change from reactive state to TS.) Even it is posible to calculate it for the macroscopic system asuming particle independence (works good for gases). The change the state of ALL molecules is the same as the change of the macroscopic system. It is hihgly unprobable, because it is the product of all individual probabilities. So, I won't happend. But, it is much more probable the change in some small set of molecules. That is why TS theory works. Only a few proporción of molecules at a time are in this more unprobable state.

Comment: Always take in mind that how big is delta G gives a measure of how much probable is one state than the other one. Suppose that your have a system with only two accesible states. And that particles are independent each others. If one state is 10 times more probable than the other one, there will be 10 times more molecules in the that state. It can sound strange becausd in macroscopic thermodynamic courses the deltas of the examples are big enought to allow considereing only one state populated.

Comment: Also, the final state (products) does not affect this ratio of particles in reactive and ts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...*according to the Second Law of Thermodynamics, entropy of the universe can only increase.*

Well, there was a [nice similar question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28022/relationship-between-evolution-and-the-increase-of-entropy-of-earth/28026#28026) in bio.SE about this. **A system is *not* universe.** The *overall* entropy of the universe increases, but that isn't true for only a particular thermodynamic system.

Also, no one said [the transition state](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2010/11/03/whats-a-transition-state/) is stable!

> The transition state of a chemical reaction is a particular configuration along the reaction coordinate. It is defined as the state corresponding to the highest potential energy along this reaction coordinate. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_state)

(High potential energy = lesser stability)

[This chemwiki.ucdavis page](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Thermodynamics/Laws_of_Thermodynamics/Second_Law_of_Thermodynamics) is also good to help reshape your understanding of second law of thermodynamics.